# I want for my xamarin project to boot from android instead of mac

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i am working on xamarin project development. I want to work on only android device. but when i build the project then it shows the message "Pair to MAC is not connected, so the build will be offline". How can i change this option form MAC to boot from Android.

Comment: remove the iOS project from your solution

Comment: unload the iOS project & set the debugging target to Android

Comment: how to unload the iOS and how to set debugging target to android

Comment: i downloaded a project which is for both android and iOS option, i want to remove iOS option, How.

Comment: Is it helpful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You could right click you Android project,and select **Set as Startup Project**.

[image]

and right click your iso project,select **Unload Project**.

[image]